# XML / Java code - remove commas from a generated system receipt

Tags: java, xml

I am using Chromis EPOS software, and the system automatically generates internal sales receipts or you can print them off. However, on the receipt after each of the products attributes it adds a comma, I am unsure if this is system controlled, or simply the way the data is being extracted from the database.

```
#if ($ticketline.productAttSetInstId)
        <line><text align ="left" length="42">${ticketline.productAttSetInstDesc}</text></line>
#end
```

That is the lines of code I have been trying to edit, to make it ignore the commas to no avail. This is written in an XML file within the software.

So if anyone has a suggestion on how to resolve this I'd be appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using java the `String.replace (",", "");`

Comment: Can I place that anywhere in the file, or does it need to be placed specifically? Sorry for sounding uneducated, but it's been a long while since I messed with programming.

Comment: The 'code' you posted above looks like an XML template, and no comma is being set by this line of 'code'. Can you locate the Java code that is calling this template?

Comment: Yes, I realised I was dealing with an XML script eventually, I did feel somewhat foolish. I have tracked down the offending commas in the correct place in the database, they're stored in two places... Which was handy I was looking at the wrong one.

I shall continue trawling through the source in NetBeans and keep looking until I find the file that deals with it directly.